# NoClassDefFoundError on **CacheModel

Tags: java, liferay, liferay-6.2

i am trying add a relationship between tables using below code

`<column name="categories" type="Collection" entity="Category" mapping-table="ShoppingItem_Category"/>`

after this have built service using **LocalServiceUtil.getCategoryItems(categoryId) this API is throwing an Exception

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/htmsd/slayer/model/impl/ShoppingItemCacheModel
at com.htmsd.slayer.model.impl.ShoppingItemModelImpl.toCacheModel(ShoppingItemModelImpl.java:618)
at com.liferay.portal.dao.orm.common.EntityCacheImpl.putResult(EntityCacheImpl.java:241)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.dao.orm.EntityCacheUtil.putResult(EntityCacheUtil.java:67)
at com.htmsd.slayer.service.persistence.ShoppingItemPersistenceImpl.cacheResult(ShoppingItemPersistenceImpl.java:1079)
at com.htmsd.slayer.service.persistence.ShoppingItemPersistenceImpl.fetchByPrimaryKey(ShoppingItemPersistenceImpl.java:1431)
at com.htmsd.slayer.service.persistence.ShoppingItemPersistenceImpl.findByPrimaryKey(ShoppingItemPersistenceImpl.java:1376)
at com.htmsd.slayer.service.persistence.ShoppingItemPersistenceImpl.findByPrimaryKey(ShoppingItemPersistenceImpl.java:1)
at com.liferay.portal.service.persistence.impl.TableMapperImpl.getBaseModels(TableMapperImpl.java:400)
at com.liferay.portal.service.persistence.impl.TableMapperImpl.getLeftBaseModels(TableMapperImpl.java:241)
at com.liferay.portal.service.persistence.impl.ReverseTableMapper.getRightBaseModels(ReverseTableMapper.java:96)
at com.htmsd.slayer.service.persistence.CategoryPersistenceImpl.getShoppingItems(CategoryPersistenceImpl.java:662)
at com.htmsd.slayer.service.persistence.CategoryPersistenceImpl.getShoppingItems(CategoryPersistenceImpl.java:641)
at com.htmsd.slayer.service.persistence.CategoryPersistenceImpl.getShoppingItems(CategoryPersistenceImpl.java:622)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:320)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:183)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
at com.liferay.portal.dao.shard.advice.ShardPersistenceAdvice.invoke(ShardPersistenceAdvice.java:54)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:90)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:202)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy1334.getShoppingItems(Unknown Source)
at com.htmsd.slayer.service.base.ShoppingItemLocalServiceBaseImpl.getCategoryShoppingItems(ShoppingItemLocalServiceBaseImpl.java:521)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.proceed(ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.java:115)
at com.liferay.portal.spring.transaction.DefaultTransactionExecutor.execute(DefaultTransactionExecutor.java:62)
at com.liferay.portal.spring.transaction.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:51)
at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.proceed(ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.java:111)
at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ChainableMethodAdvice.invoke(ChainableMethodAdvice.java:56)
at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.proceed(ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.java:111)
at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ChainableMethodAdvice.invoke(ChainableMethodAdvice.java:56)
at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.proceed(ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.java:111)
at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ChainableMethodAdvice.invoke(ChainableMethodAdvice.java:56)
at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.proceed(ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.java:111)
at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ChainableMethodAdvice.invoke(ChainableMethodAdvice.java:56)
at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.proceed(ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.java:111)
at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ChainableMethodAdvice.invoke(ChainableMethodAdvice.java:56)
at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.proceed(ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.java:111)
at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ChainableMethodAdvice.invoke(ChainableMethodAdvice.java:56)
at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.proceed(ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.java:111)
at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ChainableMethodAdvice.invoke(ChainableMethodAdvice.java:56)
at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.proceed(ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.java:111)
at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ChainableMethodAdvice.invoke(ChainableMethodAdvice.java:56)
at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.proceed(ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.java:111)
at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ChainableMethodAdvice.invoke(ChainableMethodAdvice.java:56)
at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.proceed(ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.java:111)
at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ServiceBeanAopProxy.invoke(ServiceBeanAopProxy.java:175)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy1339.getCategoryShoppingItems(Unknown Source)
at com.htmsd.slayer.service.ShoppingItemLocalServiceUtil.getCategoryShoppingItems(ShoppingItemLocalServiceUtil.java:472)
at org.apache.jsp.html.shoppinglist.view_jsp._jspService(view_jsp.java:282)
at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:116)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilter.doFilter(InvokerFilter.java:119)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:749)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doInclude(ApplicationDispatcher.java:605)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.include(ApplicationDispatcher.java:544)
at com.liferay.portlet.PortletRequestDispatcherImpl.dispatch(PortletRequestDispatcherImpl.java:331)
at com.liferay.portlet.PortletRequestDispatcherImpl.include(PortletRequestDispatcherImpl.java:112)
at com.liferay.util.bridges.mvc.MVCPortlet.include(MVCPortlet.java:371)
at com.liferay.util.bridges.mvc.MVCPortlet.include(MVCPortlet.java:387)
at com.liferay.util.bridges.mvc.MVCPortlet.doView(MVCPortlet.java:144)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.portlet.LiferayPortlet.doDispatch(LiferayPortlet.java:213)
at com.liferay.util.bridges.mvc.MVCPortlet.doDispatch(MVCPortlet.java:323)
at javax.portlet.GenericPortlet.render(GenericPortlet.java:233)
at com.liferay.portlet.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:103)
at com.liferay.portlet.ScriptDataPortletFilter.doFilter(ScriptDataPortletFilter.java:55)
at com.liferay.portlet.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:100)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.portlet.PortletFilterUtil.doFilter(PortletFilterUtil.java:64)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.PortletServlet.service(PortletServlet.java:112)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:116)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilter.doFilter(InvokerFilter.java:119)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:749)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doInclude(ApplicationDispatcher.java:605)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.include(ApplicationDispatcher.java:544)
at com.liferay.portlet.InvokerPortletImpl.invoke(InvokerPortletImpl.java:583)
at com.liferay.portlet.InvokerPortletImpl.invokeRender(InvokerPortletImpl.java:656)
at com.liferay.portlet.InvokerPortletImpl.render(InvokerPortletImpl.java:362)
at org.apache.jsp.html.portal.render_005fportlet_jsp._jspService(render_005fportlet_jsp.java:1242)
at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:116)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilter.doFilter(InvokerFilter.java:119)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:749)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doInclude(ApplicationDispatcher.java:605)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.include(ApplicationDispatcher.java:544)
at com.liferay.portal.servlet.DirectServletPathRegisterDispatcher.include(DirectServletPathRegisterDispatcher.java:55)
at com.liferay.portal.servlet.ClassLoaderRequestDispatcherWrapper.doDispatch(ClassLoaderRequestDispatcherWrapper.java:78)
at com.liferay.portal.servlet.ClassLoaderRequestDispatcherWrapper.include(ClassLoaderRequestDispatcherWrapper.java:53)
at com.liferay.portlet.PortletContainerImpl._doRender(PortletContainerImpl.java:655)
at com.liferay.portlet.PortletContainerImpl.render(PortletContainerImpl.java:138)
at com.liferay.portlet.SecurityPortletContainerWrapper.render(SecurityPortletContainerWrapper.java:141)
at com.liferay.portlet.RestrictPortletContainerWrapper.render(RestrictPortletContainerWrapper.java:126)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.portlet.PortletContainerUtil.render(PortletContainerUtil.java:156)
at com.liferay.portal.layoutconfiguration.util.PortletRenderer._render(PortletRenderer.java:125)
at com.liferay.portal.layoutconfiguration.util.PortletRenderer.render(PortletRenderer.java:72)
at com.liferay.portal.layoutconfiguration.util.RuntimePageImpl.doProcessTemplate(RuntimePageImpl.java:452)
at com.liferay.portal.layoutconfiguration.util.RuntimePageImpl.doDispatch(RuntimePageImpl.java:284)
at com.liferay.portal.layoutconfiguration.util.RuntimePageImpl.processTemplate(RuntimePageImpl.java:113)
at com.liferay.portal.layoutconfiguration.util.RuntimePageImpl.processTemplate(RuntimePageImpl.java:124)
at com.liferay.portal.layoutconfiguration.util.RuntimePageUtil.processTemplate(RuntimePageUtil.java:69)
at org.apache.jsp.html.portal.layout.view.portlet_jsp._jspService(portlet_jsp.java:557)
at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:116)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilter.doFilter(InvokerFilter.java:119)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:749)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doInclude(ApplicationDispatcher.java:605)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.include(ApplicationDispatcher.java:544)
at com.liferay.portal.action.LayoutAction.includeLayoutContent(LayoutAction.java:302)
at com.liferay.portal.action.LayoutAction.processLayout(LayoutAction.java:405)
at com.liferay.portal.action.LayoutAction.doExecute(LayoutAction.java:200)
at com.liferay.portal.action.LayoutAction.execute(LayoutAction.java:95)
at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.processActionPerform(RequestProcessor.java:431)
at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.process(RequestProcessor.java:236)
at com.liferay.portal.struts.PortalRequestProcessor.process(PortalRequestProcessor.java:179)
at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(ActionServlet.java:1196)
at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doGet(ActionServlet.java:414)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
at com.liferay.portal.servlet.MainServlet.callParentService(MainServlet.java:549)
at com.liferay.portal.servlet.MainServlet.service(MainServlet.java:526)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:116)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:169)
at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.jsoncontenttype.JSONContentTypeFilter.processFilter(JSONContentTypeFilter.java:42)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:59)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:204)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:109)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilter.doFilter(InvokerFilter.java:119)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:749)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:487)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:412)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:339)
at com.liferay.portal.servlet.FriendlyURLServlet.service(FriendlyURLServlet.java:156)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:116)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:169)
at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.strip.StripFilter.processFilter(StripFilter.java:360)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:59)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:204)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:109)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:169)
at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.gzip.GZipFilter.processFilter(GZipFilter.java:123)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:59)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:204)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:109)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:169)
at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.cache.CacheFilter.processFilter(CacheFilter.java:408)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:59)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:204)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:109)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:169)
at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.jsoncontenttype.JSONContentTypeFilter.processFilter(JSONContentTypeFilter.java:42)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:59)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:204)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:109)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:169)
at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.virtualhost.VirtualHostFilter.processFilter(VirtualHostFilter.java:226)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:59)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:204)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:109)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDirectCallFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:185)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:96)
at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriteFilter.doFilter(UrlRewriteFilter.java:738)
at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriteFilter.processFilter(UrlRewriteFilter.java:57)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:59)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:204)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:109)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDirectCallFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:165)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:96)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDirectCallFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:165)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:96)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDirectCallFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:185)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:96)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilter.doFilter(InvokerFilter.java:119)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1023)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

can anyone tell whats the problem

Comment: Hi Saleem, did u find any solution for this? I am also facing same issue..

Comment: Hi nakul, wasn't able to find the solution and i created my own mapping tables or other way would be writing custom sql for the mapping table and please revert if you find the solution